# Javascript use variable as object(array) name

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I want to use the value of a variable to access an object of array.

I want to fill a variable with this name and use the variable to access the object.

```
var data = [
    {lat_P: 37.4419, lon_P: -122.1419, title: 'location 1'},
    {lat_T: 37.4419, lon_T: -122.1419, title: 'location 2'},
   ]
```

Example:

```
let type = "T";
let geometry = "lat_" + type;
console.log(data[x].[geometry]);
```

Comment: @Archer — No, it isn't. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  The dot is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `data[x].[geometry]`. you should use `data[x][geometry]`

```js
var data = [
    {lat_P: 37.4419, lon_P: -122.1419, title: 'location 1'},
    {lat_T: 37.4419, lon_T: -122.1419, title: 'location 2'},
   ]
let type = "T";
let geometry = "lat_" + type;
console.log(data[1][geometry]);
```